# How can I print Event details in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to "pretty print" the event description?

I want all the details Who, When, Where and Description for a particular event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the event details and simply print through the browser, all the event details will be automatically laid out with a print-ready format.

Comment: I did not know that. I thought it would print the whole page..